# What can a Runner do to trash ICE that is in play?

Tags: android-netrunner

I know that the card parasite can potentially trash ice, but is there any other way? (I've just recently started playing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the only three current cards that can trash ICE after it's installed are:

- [Parasite](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/parasite-core) - program that reduces the strength of a rezzed ICE until it hits zero, at which point the ICE is trashed.
- [Forged Activation Orders](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/forged-activation-orders-core) - event that forces a Corp to rez an ice, or trash it if it can't (or doesn't want to) pay for it.
- [Kraken](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/genesis/humanitys-shadow/kraken-humanitys-shadow) - event that forces the Corp to trash a piece of ice on a server that you choose (but can only be played if you've just stolen an agenda)

In addition, there are other cards (e.g. [Imp](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/imp-what-lies-ahead), [Demolition Run](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/demolition-run-core)) that can trash cards that cannot normally be trashed - such as ICE - from HQ or R&D, preventing them from being installed in the first place.

*Edited to add:*

- [False Echo](http://www.netrunnerdb.com/en/card/04007) - program that can be trashed when you pass an unrezzed ICE to force the Corp to rez it or take it back into HQ (which is a trash-like effect)
- [Forked](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07037), [Knifed](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07038), and [Spooned](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07039) - run events that let you trash a piece of ice of a particular type if you break all subroutines on it

Comment: Note the addition of Forked, Knifed, and Spooned from Order and Chaos